# how to use fgets to get a number AND CLEAN the stdin afterward, nothing else helped

Tags: c

I am trying to get a single digit number from `stdin`.
Using `scanf("%d",&choice);` is not good because if something like `3fjios` or `fjaifdj` is entered then it keeps everything after the digit (if there is one), so if later I have `scanf("%s",name);` it takes the other chars and messing up. And also using `scanf` is bad (or so it seems from Google).

After a lot of digging I understand that we should use `fgets`, to read input into a string and then parse through it.
But! Nowhere is explained how to properly clear the buffer afterwards.
So if I do something like:

```
char choice[3];
do {
    fgets(choice, 3, stdin);
    scanf("%*[^\n]");
    scanf("%*c");//clear upto newline
} while (choice[1] != '\n');
```

this works only if I enter a string longer than 2 chars.
When I enter a single char for `fgets` then the `scanf` actually waits for another input... which is bad.

The other big problem is if I enter more than 2 chars (a digit and `'\n'`) then the first 2 chars go into `choice`, the rest are stuck in the buffer. All the approaches to clearing it seems like they require one to build a nuclear power plant first...
Also, what happens if the user enters an infinitely (a really long) long string?

Can you please show a simple way that will allow the user to enter some string of some (unknown) length, and then to properly check if it contains exactly a single digit at the start, followed by `'\n'`?
Any other input should loop back to get a new input from the user again.
please don't use complex solutions, only standard simple C please.

I can't believe I wasted 6 hours on this supposedly simple technical thing, just getting an input from the user. Solving the actual problem was easier...

Comment: Do you have to use `fgets` or are you open to any solution possible in C ?

Comment: the issue is that if you enter `456` it will retain the `6` of the second loop with your code.

Comment: just scanf with `%d` and check the return value, discarding the rest.

Comment: Blame that wasted 6 hours on a failure to follow one basic rule of learning C: "do not use scanf".  It is complicated and confuses the beginners, and using it prevents the learner from using other techniques that are actually useful to learn.  If you find a problem where scanf is appropriate, then C is probably the wrong language.

Comment: @Elyasin anything is acceptable.

Comment: @user3121023 isnt allocating 100 bytes considered a waste? the input should only have 1 digit...also how would i clear the buffer if the actual input would be 1000 chars?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala that was where i started. doesn't work properly because it retains the rest in buffer, or something.

Comment: @WilliamPursell blaming the teachers then...I was taught to get input using scanf...later with or getche but now it's not good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use scanf.  It is making things overly complicated.  Just use getchar to read and discard the line.  eg:

```
int read_input(void) {
        int n;

        n = getchar();
        if( getchar() == '\n' || n == EOF)
                return n;
        else
                do n = getchar(); while ( n != '\n' && n != EOF);
        fputs("invalid entry: ", stderr);
        return read_input();

}
int main(void) {
        int input;
        input = read_input();
        printf("user entered: %c\n", input);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have a question:
in this line:
if( getchar() == '\n' || n == EOF)
whats the n==EOF for? 
if we are reading from stdin, there is no end of file char? could you please explain this bit?

Comment: Consider `printf 5 | cmd` (cmd is your executable).  In that case, the first call to getchar returns a `'5'` (an integer value that is a 5 in the local character set).  The second call to getchar returns EOF (which is not a 'char'.  It is an integer value.)  Note that my code does *not* handle end of file well, and there are edge cases to consider.  Do not conflate stdin with a tty, and recall that even if stdin is connected to a tty you can close the input stream (on Linux, with ^d) which will cause getchar to return EOF.